# How to serialize a DTO to key-value list?

Tags: java, serialization

I want to serialize a complex DTO to a flat map of key-value pairs.

Each primitive should thereby be directly transformed to a key-value.

Each list should itself be appended with numbers according to their index inside the list.

Example:

```
public class PersonDTO {
  @XmlElement(name="THEPERSON")
  private String name;

  @XmlElement(name="THEAGE")
  private int age;

  private List<Pet> pets;
}

public class Pet {
    private String name;
    private String type;
}
```

Desired result:

```
THEPERSON=test
THEAGE=16
PETNAME_1=pabbi
PETTYPE_1=rabbit
PETNAME_2=foxy
PETTYPE_2=fox
...
PETNAME_N=...
```

Question: is there any framework that could help be in serializing a dto like this?
My DTOs may contain like 100+ fields, which I otherwise would have to transform manually.

Answer (score 1):

BeanMap is available in org.apache.commons.beanutils which will convert simple bean class with setter and getter method to map.For your use case I think You need to write similar kind of util through reflection you can get value then you find the read method for the attribute and populate the value.

code example:

```
public class BeanMapExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstName("gati");
        person.setLastNmae("sahu");
        person.setEmailId("abcd@gmail.com");
        person.getMyFriendList().add("sahu");

        BeanMap map = new BeanMap(person);

        //Iterate through keys
        Iterator<String> it = map.keyIterator();
        it = map.keyIterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = it.next();
            System.out.println(key + ": " + map.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
firstName: gati
lastNmae: sahu
emailId: abcd@gmail.com
class: class pkg1.Person
myFriendList: [sahu]
```